# Ошибка чтения DWORD из реестра в 64-разрядной системе

Tags: qt, реестр, x86-64

Есть 32-разрядное приложение Qt:

```
DWORD t;
hkey = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
path = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion";
retcode = RegOpenKeyEx(pkey, (wchar_t *) path.utf16(), 0, KEY_READ, &key)
size = sizeof(t);
name = "InstallDate";
if ((retcode = RegQueryValueEx(key, (LPCWSTR) name.utf16(), NULL, &type,  (LPBYTE) &t, &size)) != ERROR_SUCCESS) {        
  return -1;
}
if (t == 0) { // что то странное творится в 64 разрядной ОС
    log_debug("Дата инсталляции не считана\n");
}
```

В 32-разрядной системе всё нормально, а в 64-разрядной выдает `0`. В чем проблема? Компилятор *mingw32*.

Comment: Про чтение реестра 32 битной программой на 64 битной машине надо объяснять? Вроде тема достаточно известная. Подсказка, есть ещё ветка реестра **SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node** загляните туда.

Comment: У меня 64 битная машина. В ветке HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion значение InstallDate не нулевое, а в HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion как правильно показывает ваша программа значение равное 0.

Comment: Если Вы используете Qt, то почему не используете встроенные [возможности](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsettings.html#accessing-the-windows-registry-directly)?

Comment: @cybrex, может ответ напишите?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас значение 0 потому, что 32 битная программа на 64 битной машине читает из другой ветки реестра. Какие именно ветки написал выше в комментариях. Как [пишет](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa384129(v=vs.85).aspx) microsoft, надо использовать специальный ключ для перенаправления в нужную ветку:

> KEY_WOW64_64KEY   0x0100  Access a 64-bit key from either a 32-bit or 64-bit application.

То есть код будет выглядеть как-то так.

```
retcode = RegOpenKeyEx(pkey, (wchar_t *) path.utf16(), 0, KEY_WOW64_64KEY | KEY_READ, &key)
```

Имейте ввиду что, работает он начиная с Windows 7:

> Windows Server 2008, Windows Vista, Windows Server 2003, and Windows XP:  The KEY_WOW_64_64KEY flag does not affect whether a key is replaced. This flag affects replacement starting with Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2.

Но как было написано в другом комментарии, если используете Qt то лучше делать это средствами Qt, а не WinApi. Как именно не подскажу, так как не знаю)

Comment: спасибо, дошло, лопухнулся. А средствами WinAPI мне необходимо потому, что будет соединение с удаленным реестром.